# How to save values as .txt file then recover later?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, variables, save, text-files

How can I recover numeric data from a saved .txt file? WinForms VB.NET.

An example of the data to save/recover is:

`1.62,1.34,1.50,0.34`

Etc etc. I want to be able to dim each number as a decimal for further use.

I will have saved a .txt file on the user's computer in a known location and (providing it hasn't been deleted) want to recover the numeric data I saved in there. Which layout should I use to save it in the first place to later easily recover the data? How should I recover it?

I am aware that My.Settings offers far simpler functionality for this, but it seems to be quite hit and miss in terms of reliability (actually saving and returning the best correct values) for me and I want a reliable solution.

Comment: In terms of *accuracy*? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @minitech Accuracy meaning it hardly ever stores the result correctly

Comment: My.settings should work fine. If you want to save something between sessions, you can also use the registry, or you can save the data in various formats - csv, xml, one you dream up yourself - in a text file. As it stands, your question is too broad to give a meaningful answer - we need more context.

Comment: how will `My.Settings` saving it as a decimal be less accurate than writing it to a text file??

Comment: A reliable solution would be a database...

Comment: @Plutonix for some reason `My.Settings` does not seem to want to work for me. It almost never returns the value I saved.

Comment: @peterG so i want to save a .txt with a string/array of numeric values. Then i want to recover them at a later date.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR how would a database work? Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are a few values, `My.Settings` with a few Decimals will work fine.  For a modest number of values you can use serialization on a `List` to avoid the overhead of a database:

```
Friend decList As New List(Of Decimal)
' use the values from here if you like and forego individual vars
' it rather works like an array:

thisDec = decList(index)
```

Saving and loading values is easy and fast:

```
Private Sub SaveList
   Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(myFileName,
           FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)

        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        bf.Serialize(fs, decList)
   End Using
End Sub

Private Sub LoadList
   ' ToDo: check if file exists for the first time run if a file
   '   of defaults is not available
   Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(myFileName,
           FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        decList = CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), List(Of Decimal))
   End Using
End Sub
```

The Deserializer returns an object, so you need to cast it to the proper type under `Option Strict`.  Otherwise, the entire list is recreated.  `Classes`, `lists of classes`, `lists of dictionaries of class` can all be easily serialized.  Even many things that cannot be serialized can easily be converted to something that can be.

Depending on what these values are, you might want to use a Dictionary instead.  This allows you to reference the values by key (name, Enum, Int...).  A string key acts as a name more or less for the values so they can be used directly from the collection.  This avoids packing and unpacking the collection for serialization:

```
Friend colDec As New Dictionary(of String, Decimal)

' add a value with the key of "Foo"
colDec.Add("Foo", 3.14285714285714)

' add a var value with the key of "Bar"
colDec.Add("Bar", decX)

' reference them in the collection:
decFooBar = colDec("Foo") + colDec("Bar")     ' sum
```

Serializing is the same, deserialize needs a mod for the new type:

```
colDec= CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), Dictionary(of String, Decimal))
```

Comment: Where do I insert the values? And in which format should I present them to separate them?

Comment: `decList.Add(decimal_value)` adds one to the list.  if they are decimal variables, you dont need to format them except maybe for display purposes.  Each is already a seperate value stored in a separate element in the list, so I dont know what you mean by separate them.  The comments and that My.Settings doesnt work leads me to think you have conversion issues going on, maybe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Accepted your answer.

Comment: If you upvote my question I'll have enough Reputation to upvote your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I added some info on using a `Dictionary` instead of a `List` which might be more applicable